Error: unable to locate package in Linux mint
I am a newbie who recently installed Linux. My problem is that I can't install any program or package, and even when updating the packages, I get an error. My error is Error: unable to locate package.
Some of the people I asked said that the problem is with DNS and you have to change it, but I don't know because I tried it according to what I found on the internet, but it was dns.
